# In oder im Lotto gewinnen?

Tags: grammar, spelling

Wie wäre denn die korrekte Schreibweise?

Beispiel:
`Ich würde gerne in/im Lotto gewinnen.`

Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass `im` richtig wäre, aber auch nur, weil ich es immer so höre. Ist denn das auch korrekt, umgeangssprachlich oder hat es sich falsch eingebügert?

**Welche Wortwahl ist hier korrekt?**

Comment: Es ist keine Frage der Schreibweise, sondern der Wortwahl. Es gibt die veraltete Schreibweise Cöllen für Köln, aber es bezeichnet das gleiche Ding, die Stadt. *In* und *Im* sind aber unterschiedliche Worte; es sind nicht zwei Schreibweisen des gleichen Wortes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"im" ist korrekt.

Warum?

**"im"** = Kurzform von **"in dem"**.

> Ich habe **in dem** (Spiel) Lotto gewonnen.
>
> Ich habe **in dem** Lotto-Spiel gewonnen.

---

> Ich habe **in** Tetris (gegen Spieler) gewonnen. – Korrekt
>
> Ich habe **in** Aachen (gegen Spieler) gewonnen. – Korrekt (**Ort**)
>
> Ich habe **in** der **Spielumgebung** Tetris gewonnen. – Korrekt (**Ort**)
>
> Ich habe **in** World of Warcraft einen Ork erlegt. – Korrekt (**Ort**)
>
> Ich habe **im** Schach gewonnen.
>
> Ich habe **in** Moskau **im** Schach gegen Mr. X gewonnen.

---

„Tetris“ ist ein Eigenname und wird ohne Artikel geschrieben. Deshalb kann es weder „in der Tetris“ noch „in dem Tetris“ heißen, demzufolge also auch nicht „im“. (Ausnahmen unten)

> Ich habe **im** Spiel Tetris (gegen Spieler) gewonnen. – Korrekt
>
> Ich habe **im** Tetris (gegen Spieler) gewonnen. – Unüblich (im
>   Tetris-Spiel)
>
> Ich habe in Tetris gewonnen. (Erklärung s. o.)

---

> Ich habe **in** Tetris, der **Spielesimulation**/**Spieleumgebung** gewonnen.

Comment: Selbe Frage wie bei der anderen Antwort: Wäre dann `Ich habe in COMPUTERSPIELNAME gewonnen` falsch?

Comment: Wann sage ich denn "in Tetris" und wann "im Tetris"?

Comment: „Tetris“ ist ein Eigenname und wird ohne Artikel geschrieben. Deshalb kann es weder „in der Tetris“ noch „in dem Tetris“ heißen, also auch nicht „im“.

Comment: Ah, ich denke Piefel hat das Entscheidende beigetragen. :) Kann man das der Antwort hinzufügen?

Comment: Done, im Tetris(Spiel) gewonnen works (for me). But I agree in dem Tretris gewonnen sounds weird.

Answer (score 9):

„*Im*“ ist schlicht eine Zusammenschreibung von „*in dem*“, also eine [Verschmelzung von Präposition und Artikel](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Prep-Art/index.html). Wenn Du nur `in` verwendest, lässt Du quasi den Artikel weg - das ist regelmäßig grammatikalisch nicht korrekt. Auch die Aufspaltung „*Ich würde gerne in dem Lotto gewinnen*“ ist komplett ungebräuchlich, daher würde ich hier die Verschmelzung Präposition-Artikel als [obligatorisch](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Prep-Art/Gebrauch.html#Anchor-Verschmelzung-21683) ansehen. Korrekt ist daher nur „***im Lotto***“ (siehe auch die [Beispiele zur Verwendung des Substantivs „Lotto“ im Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lotto)).

Comment: Sehr logisch! Blöde Frage, aber was unterscheidet das dann von `habe in COMPUTERSPIELNAME gewonnen`? Oder wäre dies dann falsch?

Comment: Kommt drauf an :-) - in bestimmten Fällen steht tatsächlich kein Artikel - „ich habe den schwarzen Gürtel in Mikado“ z.B., also nicht „im Mikado“ (umgangssprachlich schon). Bei der Konstruktion „habe im ... gewonnen“ würde ich aber „im“ erwarten, nicht „in“ (autoritative Quelle: Bauchgefühl).

Comment: Das wäre eigentlich der Kern meiner Frage, wann man dann in/im verwendet. :) Kann man das klären?

Comment: Oh oh - da kann ich nichts anbieten, nur weitere Beispiele - „in Englisch“, aber „im Englischen“. Vielleicht: wenn das Abstraktum gemeint ist (die englische Sprache, die Sportart Karate), dann „in“ - wenn ein konkretes Ereignis (Lottogewinn etc.) gemeint ist, dann „im“. Bin mir aber nicht sicher.

Comment: Wäre super, wenn man hierzu eine Quelle finden könnte. :) Aber schon mal vielen Dank fürs Mitwirken!